# Price and Total fields are empty in Woocommerce Cart

Tags: woocommerce

Since Woocommerce 3 update, the fields Price and Total are empty in the cart table, has anyone ever met this issue ?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? It is helpful to turn off plugins one at a time, and also to switch to a default theme. Try that and provide a lot more detail. You aren't providing much information here to go on, but if I had to guess, your theme is not up to date for WooCommerce 3.0.

Comment: thanks, it's the same with default theme and without extension...

Comment: i think you are right the problem comes with the plug woocomerce Extra options